# Is it possible to draw a border with 1 angled corner?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm hoping to draw a solid border around a div, the only catch is that I'd like 1 corner to be "dog eared" (see attached image).

Is this possible to do in CSS? I've found clip-path, but this doesn't seem to accept a border willingly.

Please note that I will want to fill this area with content as well - text/images.

[image: border with dog ear/fold]

Comment: Have you tried SVG?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I have not, are you suggesting to use an SVG as a background image for the div?

Comment: I was suggesting that, but I see that there a lot of better answers out there. I would recommend one of the CSS based answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with linear gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,red 50%,transparent 0) 0 0/calc(100% - 20px) 2px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 50%,red 0) 0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to right,red 50%,transparent 0) 0 0/2px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to right,transparent 50%,red 0) 100% 20px/2px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,red 50%,red calc(50% + 1px),transparent calc(50% + 2px)) 100% 0/20px 20px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

For the clip-path solution you can do this:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50% ,red 0) 100% 0/20px 20px no-repeat;
  border:2px solid red;
  clip-path:polygon(1px 1px,1px calc(100% - 1px),calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 1px),calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 84px), calc(100% - 20px) 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here is another way using pseudo element and skew transformation:

```css
.box {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top: none;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same.  you should blur a bit the slang part to make it look better ;) : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyrYKZ

Comment: Very interesting. So is the linear gradient just "covering" the upper right corner and drawing an angled line?

Comment: @brendo234 well i used 5 gradient for each line ... 4 straight one and the one at the angle with a diagonal direction :) as you can see i simply spcified the color at 2px for this gradient

Comment: @G-Cyr like updated ? :)

Comment: @brendo234 i also added more ways if intrested ;)